# Extracting Specific Links with Beauttiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract specific links from the following HTML code.

```
 <div class="RadAjaxPanel" id="LiveBoard1_LiveBoard1_litGamesPanel">
<br /><b><a href="winss.aspx?team=White Sox&pos=all&stats=bat&qual=0&type=8&season=2018&month=0&season1=2018">White Sox</a></b> @ <b><a href="winss.aspx?team=Athletics&pos=all&stats=bat&qual=0&type=8&season=2018&month=0&season1=2018">Athletics</a></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;15:35 ET<br /><center><table style="width:360px;"><tr><td align="center" width="120.07295665741px" style="border:1px solid black;">33.4 %</td><td align="center" width="239.92704334259px" style="border:1px solid black;">66.6 %</td></tr><table></center><br /><center><table style="width:360px;" class="lineup"><tr><td align="left">SP: <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=18311&position=P">Carson Fulmer</a></td><td align="left">SP: <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=13533&position=P">Andrew Triggs</a></td></tr><tr><td align="left">1. <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=17232&position=2B">Yoan Moncada</a> (2B)<br />2. <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=11602&position=2B">Yolmer Sanchez</a> (3B)<br />3. <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=15676&position=1B">Jose Abreu</a> (DH)<br />4. <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=13157&position=OF">Nick Delmonico</a> (LF)<br />5. <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=7226&position=3B/DH">Matt Davidson</a> (1B)<br />6. <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=5913&position=OF">Leury Garcia</a> (RF)<br />7. <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=3256&position=C">Welington Castillo</a> (C)<br />8. <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=15172&position=SS">Tim Anderson</a> (SS)<br />9. <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=15082&position=OF">Adam Engel</a> (CF)<br /></td>
```

I want the final extraction to include the team name, in this case, that's Athletics and White Sox, and the corresponding win probabilities (33.4% and 66.6%). I can extract all those links using beautiful soup, but I am not able to delete the lineup links. I noticed all the lineup links start with "statss." Is there any way to tell beautiful soup to decompose the "statss" links when extracting all the links on the page? My current code is displayed below. As you can tell, I have tried using the decompose function by attempting to find class=lineup, but the output still returns the entire lineup. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page=requests.get('https://www.fangraphs.com/livescoreboard.aspx?date=2018- 
04-18')
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

#Remove Lineup Links
lineup_links=soup.find(class_='lineup')
lineup_links.decompose()

team_name_list=soup.find(class_='RadAjaxPanel')
team_name_list_items=team_name_list.find_all('a')


for team_name in team_name_list_items:
 print(team_name.prettify())


odds_list=soup.find(class_='RadAjaxPanel')
odds_list_items=odds_list.find_all('td',attrs={'style':'border:1px solid 
black;'})

for odds in odds_list_items:
 print(odds.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're deleting the first instance of the lineups, not every single one. Try looping though the links and decomposing them one by one, like:

```
#Remove Lineup Links
[link.decompose() for link in soup.find_all(class_='lineup')]
```